# Can Amazon Cognito Services replace ASP.NET Identity Management?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, amazon-cognito

We have used ASP.NET Identity Management in a website. It is used to authenticate users as well as manage their Roles to access specific functionality of website.
My question, Is Cognito something that meant for similar purpose? Can it replace ASP.NET Identity Management? Does it hold functionality for creating, managing and assigning Roles to users to access specific features/pages of my website?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, the functionality is very similar although there might be some subtle differences. Cognito allows you to add authentication to your application. And with the new groups feature, it allows particular users to have access to specific resources.

Comment: Thanks Lonut, It seems like I can make use of Groups as Indentity Roles to decide user has access to particular page or not by adding them to a Group and use that Group as a Role